# How to get json schema $ref data from servlet

Tags: java, jsonschema

I need to get data from servlet when I pass schema like below.

`attrServlet` is servlet call.

```
{
    "id": "../test#",
    "$schema": "../schema#",
    "title": "Test",
    "type": "object",
    "format":"grid",
    "required": [
        "/"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "/": 
        { 
            "title":"value",
            "$ref": "http://00.00.00.00:8080/Test/attrServlet/#" 
        }
    }
}
```

In the place of `$ref`, I need servlet data. My data coming through servlet into browser but on front end it's not reflecting. Any idea?

Comment: My first guess is, is your servlet data a valid JSON schema? I mean maybe your data is a JSON body, but by mistake it's not a JSON schema. Please double check it.

Comment: What validator do you use?